# How to convert C++ *.lib file to unsafe C# interop?

Tags: c#, c++, .net

How to convert C++ *.lib file to unsafe C# interop? I need converter.

Update:

I have `Win32` dll + lib + headers (*.dll, *.lib *.h). And i need generate in style:

```
[DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern bool CopySid(uint nDestinationSidLength, IntPtr pDestinationSid,IntPtr pSourceSid); + structures
```

But instead of `IntPtr` use `int*` or so (unsafe style).

Comment: Please see updated topic

Answer (score 2):

There's no inherent method to take an arbitrary library and roll it into .NET.

You can take existing COM DLL's, import their type libraries, and create "wrappers" that are essentially proxies from the managed .NET framework into the unmanaged COM world.

Beyond that, you'll probably have to do some reading on PInvoke, and try as best you can to get a better understanding of exactly what kinds of function(s) are held in that library.

Without more information, it's very difficult to give you a great deal more direction than that. I hope that's at least a start.

Comment: I need generate win32API interop, not COM.

Comment: You'll likely need to consider writing a COM-based C++ wrapper around that library, then importing those interfaces into your C# app.

Comment: Why do I need to do so if I can call the API through DllImport? Example in topic. I can write everything myself, but I was hoping that there is a utility ...

Comment: I know of no utility to do the kinds of conversions you're asking for here. When you start looking into passing IntPtr's from managed to unmanaged code, things get very tricky very quickly. I'm not sure you are going to be able to leverage these API's quite as readily as you are suspecting. That's why there was a suggestion of a C++ "wrapper" app - one that could in a custom way handle some of those kinds of conversions that no generic utility could necessarily understand in full. Sorry there's not as clean a solution available as you might have hoped. Have an awesome day.

Comment: COM works so slowly... :), and managed code what use marshal. I write app what will be work on real time and high performance. I found tool from [link](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/misc.Helpful%20Tools) and [link](http://www.paulyao.com/res/pinvoke/Pinvoke.aspx). For me unsafe code its a no problem. PS: Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure exactly what you want as you have not provided a context to your question, but if you're asking what I think you are, you may want to read up on [PInvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/).

Comment: PInvoke is not have dll what i need.

Comment: And i need native unsafe generation not marshal.